# What is a "consecutive stay plan"?

Tags: japan, bookings, hotels, terminology

We're trying to book a hotel room in Japan. There are two options for the same room and same duration: with or without "consecutive stay plan", the latter being slightly less expensive (e.g. 199 vs 204 USD).

The info popup is not helpful; there might be a difference in cancellation policy, but it is really hard to parse.

Web searching yields only results related to Japan.

EDIT: we're searching on jalan.net. Here's an [example booking query in English](https://www.jalan.net/en/japan_hotels_ryokan/Hotels/Tokyo_Hotels/Katsushika_Edogawa_Koto_Hotels/Koto_Hotels/super_hotel_tokyo-kameido/?minPriceUsd=0&maxPriceUsd=4000&langCd=en_US&stayYear=2024&stayMonth=May&stayDay=4&stayCount=2&roomCount=1&distCd=01&mealTypeBFst=1&roomTwin=1&roomDouble=1&roomCrack=200000) (for May 2024, so it might be expired for future readers). I unfortunately can not switch to Japanese, only to other languages.

Here's a screenshot of the English listing:

[image: screenshot of the listing]And here's the info popup:

[image]

Comment: It’s quite possible this is an incorrect translation. Where are you trying to book? Is there a possibility to have a Japanese version which you could use in Google Translate and see the different alternatives, or provide here for someone else to translate? The price difference makes me think of a cancellable vs. prepaid booking, though the difference is usually a bit higher (about 10%) for that.

Comment: @jcaron thanks, I've added some hopefully helpful context

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A consecutive stay (連泊) plan means basically the same in English, although it may be kind of strange to show it for English-speaking audience due to differences in marketing traditions (just like how hotels advertising an "early bird" rate may be confusing for non-English audience too).

It is a discount rate for staying for two or more nights at the same hotel. This discount rate may or may not be cheaper than other discounted rates. It may or may not have more restrictive cancellation policies. If you decide to end your stay earlier, you may be no longer eligible for this rate, whereas for standard rates you may have more flexibility.

Comment: Makes sense! @Doc's answer might be more practical, but I think this answers the core of my question concisely, if more abstractly

Comment: This is what we call a "literal translation" (AKA word-for-word translation). Literal translations sometimes make no sense in the other language. I worked in a motel in Australia where we would give people a discount for 2nd and consecutive nights if they asked, but I don't think we had any specific terminology for it. Basically it costs a place more to prepare a room for new guests than for guests staying multiple days, assuming it's not fancy enough to be serviced daily of course.

Comment: So it is essentially a promise to stay for X nights and accept a higher cost if you break the promise? It makes sense that they'd offer you a lower rate then if it guarantees income.

Comment: @hippietrail "Basically it costs a place more to prepare a room for new guests than for guests staying multiple days" There's an argument for AirBnB's policy of allowing a separate cleaning fee, since it effectively means that the per-day price is lower for longer stays. With a rate based solely on number of nights, per-visit costs such as cleaning are subsidized by people staying longer.

Answer (score 15):

The rate appears to be exactly what the description (if not title) of that pop-up shows - a "length-of-stay required" rate, or what is normally known as a "minimum stay" rate.

It's not uncommon for hotels to have different rates available for the same room - with different conditions and benefits for each rate.  Some of these are obvious - things like "breakfast included" in one rate whilst another may not include it, and differences in cancelation fees between rates.

Sometimes the prices for these different rates makes sense, and sometimes they don't seem to.  eg, I've seen rates where the "breakfast included" rate is cheaper than the exact same rate (with same cancelation policy/etc) without breakfast.  Although this doesn't seem to make sense, there could be a good reason for it - such as one rate being used as the basis for negotiated rates with companies/etc. It's also possible that some rates are only available directly via the hotel, whilst the other rates are available via other travel booking websites/agents as well.

Now, back to your example.  The 2nd rate here appears to have a "minimum stay" restriction of 2 nights.  If you search for the same stay but for once 1 night, you won't see that rate.  Normally such a rate would be cheaper (per night) than a non-minimum-stay rate, or have some other benefits over the normal rates (maybe a better cancelation condition).  In this case the benefits and cancelation policy does appear to be the same, and as you've pointed out it's actually more expensive.  It does seem to have one additional benefits which is that "Reservation possible without a credit card", which might be why it's more expensive, or it might be due to one of the other reasons mentioned above.

Presuming you're willing to provide a credit card during reservation there does not seem to be any reason/benefit to select this higher rate, so I'd just go with the cheaper one!

Comment: Could the "Reservation possible without a credit card" imply that you only supply your credit card when you check in?  Because I've seen many hotels charging more for this feature.

Comment: While @xngtng's answer is more concise and to the point, this provides valuable practical info. Future readers: read both :)

Comment: @PeterM It makes sense that they do.  If they have your card, they can charge you for a night's stay if you don't show up (a "no-show fee"), so there's less risk to them.  If you don't provide your card until you show up, and then you don't show up, they've got an empty room they can't rent for the night.  So if you _do_ show up, they charge you more to cover the risk from other people who didn't provide a card and didn't show.